# "Add <directory>" in hive cli

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata, hadoop-streaming

I want something like

```
$hive
> ADD FILE <directory_path>;
```

which adds a directory to working directory of hive.

I am using hive 0.7.
I need this for addding python packages to be used by mapper/reducer scripts.
What are my options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me is zipping all the content (directory/files) to a zip file and using 'ADD ARCHIVE ' as explained in [Add multiple files to distributed cache in HIVE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15429040/add-multiple-files-to-distributed-cache-in-hive)

Answer (score 1):

For 0.7.1 you can use the shell escape (!) to run `!hadoop fs -mkdir <path>` or the "dfs" command `dfs -mkdir <path>`. See the [cli wiki page](https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/languagemanual-cli.html) for more info. Not sure if these are in 0.7 or not.

Comment: This doesn't work. I nned the directory to be appended to distributed cache to be used by mapper reducer scripts in hive