# Add multiple files to distributed cache in HIVE

Tags: hadoop, hive

I currently have an issue adding a folders contents to Hives distrusted cache. I can successfully add multiple files to the distributed cache in Hive using:

```
ADD FILE /folder/file1.ext;
ADD FILE /folder/file2.ext;
ADD FILE /folder/file3.ext;
etc.
```

.

I also see that there is a `ADD FILES` (plural) option which in my mind means you could specify a directory like: `ADD FILES /folder/;` and everything in the folder gets included (this works with Hadoop Streaming -files option). But this does not work with Hive. Right now I have to explicitly add each file.

Am I doing this wrong? Is there a way to had a whole folders contents to the distributed cache.

P.S. I tried wild cards `ADD FILE /folder/*` and `ADD FILES /folder/*` but that fails too.

**Edit:**

As of hive 0.11 this now supported so:

```
ADD FILE /folder
```

now works.

What I am using is passing the folder location to the hive script as a param so:

```
$ hive -f my-query.hql -hiveconf folder=/folder
```

and in the my-query.hql file:

```
ADD FILE ${hiveconf:folder}
```

Nice and tidy now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add doesn't support directories, but as a workaround you can **zip** the files. Then add the it to the distributed cache as an *archive* (`ADD ARCHIVE my.zip`). When the job is running the content of the archive will be unpacked on the local job directory of the
slave nodes (see the `mapred.job.classpath.archives` property)

If the number of the files you want to pass is relatively small, and you don't want deal with archives you can also write a small script which prepares the *add file command* for all the files you have in a given directory: 
E.g:

```
#!/bin/bash
#list.sh

if [ ! "$1" ]
then
  echo "Directory is missing!"
  exit 1
fi

ls -d $1/* | while read f; do echo ADD FILE $f\;; done
```

Then invoke it from the Hive shell and execute the generated output:

```
!/home/user/list.sh /path/to/files
```

Comment: I have the same use case. For me archive is not being unpacked. Do I need to set mapred.job.classpath.archives property? If yes to what value? A link to the documentation will be perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Well, in my case, I had to move a folder with child folders and files in it.

I used the `ADD ARCHIVE xxx.gz`, which was adding the file, but was *not* exploding(unzipping) in the slave machines.

Instead, `ADD FILE <folder_name_without_traling_slash>` actually copies the whole folder recursively to the slaves.

Courtesy: [The comments helped debugging](http://qnalist.com/questions/4392895/is-there-a-mechanism-similar-to-hadoop-archive-in-hive-add-archive-is-not-apparently)

Hope this helps !